# How to test if a Subset of a Ring is an Ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've been browsing Ideal test and I'm trying to understand what constitutes a concise and efficient method of testing to see if a subset is an ideal of a ring.

I understand For $I$ to be an ideal of a ring $R(+,\cdot)$ (sorry if the LaTeX is wrong.) it must satisfy the following:

-$I$ must be a subgroup of the group $R$ under addition

-for all $x\in I$ and all* $y\in R$ $xy=yx\in I$

*am I right in saying all here

So my question is. What is the minimal amount of testing needed to be done to show $I$ is indeed an Ideal of $R$?

Comment: My friend believe it suffices to show

- $0\in I$

- for $a,b\in I then a+b\in I$

- $\forall r \in R and a\in I$,     then,     $ar=ra\in I$

PS cant figure out why 'then' and 'and' are coming out bold and annoying.

Comment: $xy=yx$ is not necessary.

Comment: You don't need to show $xy = yx$ because it's not part of the definition of an ideal.